# Disqus phonegap

Tags: angularjs, cordova, disqus

I use the following snippet to embed Disqus thread into my app. Everything works fine in browser. But on mobile devices, I can only scroll the page out side of the view area. I tried mobile browser, and PhoneGap app, they have the same issue.

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var disqus_shortname = 'short_name'; // the forum shortname we created
        var disqus_identifier = 'thread_id'; // unique id of the thread we created

        // SSO snippet

        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); 
            dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; 
            dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
```

The screenshot follows[image]

Comment: Are you using a UI framework like Sencha? Many of them have custom scroll containers that play nicely with the Disqus iframe. Try embedding on a regular HTML page and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: We use PhoneGap. Using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I added `overflow-scroll="true"` attribute to my `ion-content` element and problem has gone for me.

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content padding="20" overflow-scroll="true">
    <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
    {{ article.content }}

    <disqus shortname="muratcorlu"></disqus>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```